# How to replace character inside string in java

Tags: java

I have a string similar to the one below:

```
String abc = "122222";
```

and I want to be able to replace a specified character inside string, so the '1' becomes '2' in the example above.

Comment: `"122222".replace("1","2");`

Answer (score 4):

Simply do:

```
abc = abc.replace('1', '2');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String abc = "122222";
abc = abc.replace('1','2');
```

Comment: It's Java, so you need to use double quotes.

Comment: @enrmarc no. there are two replace methods.

Comment: even single quote is fine

Comment: @MarcoForberg you are right. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence%29) method of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
String abc = "122222";
abc = abc.replace("1", "2");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `replaceFirst` if you want to replace only the first `1`

```
String abc = "122222";
abc = abc.replaceFirst("1","2");
```

because `replace` will replace all occurrences of `1` in `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search for the [java string API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)  would have given you what you needed. With examples too.

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer

Comment: Teaching the man to fish

Answer (score 0):

Here i am replacing "2" with "3" test this.

```
public class TextDemo {
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    String a = "11112bbbb";
    int b = a.indexOf("2");
    String c = a.substring(0, b);
    String d = a.substring(b);
    String e = d.substring(1);
    String f = "3" + e;
    String finalString = c + f;

    System.out.println(finalString);

}
```

Comment: a bit complicated and you forgot to check whether `indexOf()` returned -1

Comment: @Macro Forberg  I have given basic idea , need some validation check..:)